# What is Content Download Chrome Debug Tool?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, jsp, web

What is Content Download??
Is there any way to speed up?
[image]

Comment: To view Google's official documentation on network timing, click the "Explanation" link at the bottom-left corner of the popup, which leads [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#timing-explanation).

Answer (score 1):

Content Download is, like the name would suggest, the time it takes that the Content is Downloaded :P

For Example, when the request is an Image, it is the time that this image is effective downloaded. So After all the negation is done, and the Client sent the request to the Server.

How it can be speed up?

- faster Internet connection
- smaller Filesize (compression, minify, caching, etc.)
- ... everything that increase your speed to download something